# Rlim versus tensor product

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a coherent ring, and let $(M_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(N_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be two inverse systems of finitely generated flat $R$-modules. If $R^1 \lim M_n=R^1 \lim N_n = 0$, is it true also that $R^1 \lim (M_n \otimes_R N_n)=0$? This seems very reasonable but I'm having trouble seeing it.

A more conceptual question: is there a reasonably general "Kunneth formula" for $R\lim$ on inverse systems of $R$-modules?

Comment: You don't specify a right $R$-action on the $M_n$ and a left on the $N_n$; do you want $R$ to be commutative?